# Using C++, while making a console application is there a way for cin to accept the next character entered and continue without hitting enter?

Tags: c++

We just covered screen control in my C++ class and I want to make a console app where you can move a "X" around the screen with the use of w,a,s,d, but I don't want the user to have to hit enter.

Comment: I don't understand, what is ":::::::ncurses"?

Comment: It's a [code library](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) used in *nix for doing the kinds of console manipulations you are talking about.  The pdcurses I describe below is a cross-platform version of it.  The techniques that you are proposing are not difficult, but they require some manipulations of stdin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible with standard C++.  You will need a cross-platform library like [pdcurses](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net) or the conio library (originally from DOS), or a  related platform-dependent library.

Comment: @wilhelmtell conio was originally a dos library, but can be used in a console in Windows.  I should clarify.